# MAC: QT get OpenGl core-profile working

Tags: macos, qt, opengl

I am trying to develop an app with Qt.
I am using a MacBook-Pro Retina.
The problem is, I can't get the Core Profile working.
If I try to compile my shaders, there is a warning:

> version 330 not supported.

The QGL-Widget is created with the Designer.

Any one has experience with QGL-Widgets?
Here is my code:

```
void MyGLWidget::initializeGL(){

    QGLFormat format;
    format.setVersion(3,2);
    format.setProfile(QGLFormat::CoreProfile);
    format.setSampleBuffers(true);
    QGLFormat::setDefaultFormat(format);

    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);        //  Tiefenpufferung
    glDisable(GL_CULL_FACE);
    glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL);         //  Neue Fragmente bestehen den Vergleich, wenn sie einen kleineren oder gleichgroßen Tiefenwert haben.
    glHint(GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL_NICEST);

    glClearDepth(1.0f);                       //legt den Wert fest, mit dem der Tiefenpuffer beim löschen beschrieben werden soll
    //glClearColor(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);   //analog zu glClearDepth
    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

    createBuffer();

    shaderProgram.addShaderFromSourceFile(QOpenGLShader::Vertex, ":/default330.vert");
    shaderProgram.addShaderFromSourceFile(QOpenGLShader::Fragment, ":/default330.frag");
    shaderProgram.link();
}
```

Comment: does OSX support OGL3.3? you can use 4.1 instead.

Comment: "*format.setVersion(3,2);*" GLSL 3.30 cannot be used with GL 3.2 contexts.